# async Task Wait behavior in static constructor waits for entire time even though task has finished

Tags: c#, async-await, task

When calling `Task.Run(..)..Wait(...)` in a static constructor it waits for the entire timeout time even though the task has finished. Just curious why this is? What is best practice for this scenario? Test class that shows it below

```cs
    static TestClass()
    {
        var delay = 100;
        var wait = 500;

        // Will wait the whole wait time
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Task.Run(() => DoStuff(delay)).Wait(wait);
        sw.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed {elapsedMs}");
     
        // Will return when task is complete
        sw.Restart();
        Task.Run(()=>
        {
            var awaiter = Task.Run(() => DoStuff(delay)).GetAwaiter();
            var maxMs = delay * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            var swElapse = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            while (!awaiter.IsCompleted && swElapse.ElapsedTicks < maxMs)
            { }
            swElapse.Stop();
        }).Wait(wait);
        sw.Stop();
        elapsedMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed {elapsedMs}");
    }

    static void DoStuff(int delay)
    {
        // Some async task called and waited for result
        Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(100)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to avoid doing any asynchronous action in any type of constructor.

Comment: Quite a few things wrong here.  Just like spinning up a `Thread` only to `Join`, why bother spinning-up a CPU-bound `Task` only to block on it until it finishes?  That defeats the purpose of threading and `Task`s.   Why does `DoStuff` spin up **another** CPU-bound `Task` that does the `Task` equivalent of `Join`.  That's a waste of a thread and defeats the purpose of `Task`...in fact you are doing this everywhere in your constructor.   As a general programming rule, you should avoid doing anything in a constructor that can result in exceptions being thrown (apart from validation of parameters)

Comment: ...also `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` _["...will synchronously block until the task completes. As such, it is subject to the same old deadlock problems as Wait and Result....](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in a static constructor

Last time I checked, static constructors *take a lock* because only one of them can execute at a time. So, if the static constructor queues work to another thread that then does other things (i.e., call other static constructors) while the original static constructor is *blocked* on that other thread, then [you can end up with a deadlock](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/static-constructor-deadlocks/) that is only resolved with the timeout.

> What is best practice for this scenario?

[Don't block on `async` code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), especially not in constructors, and especially *especially* not in static constructors. (Link is to my blog).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var delay = 100;
    var maxMs = delay * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    var secondsTotal = maxMs / 1000.0m;
    Console.WriteLine("Total seconds thread will wait: " + secondsTotal + "s.");
```

When you run this code, you get: 1000s. 1000 seconds is 16.7 minutes.

Your while condition is:

```
!awaiter.IsCompleted && swElapse.ElapsedTicks < maxMs
```

Because this is the "AND" operation, the while loop will continue so long as what's in the parentheses is true.

In your case the "awaiter.IsCompleted" evaluates for true, AND less than 16 minutes evaluates for true as well (until 16 minutes pass). Only until one of the conditions is false will the while loop stop repeating.

This is likely why you are experiencing this behavior.

Comment: _"In your case the "awaiter.IsCompleted" evaluates for true"_ - I think that should read _"In your case the `!awaiter.IsCompleted` evaluates for true"_.  Anyway your conclusion is incorrect, as soon as the `Task` completes `swElapse.ElapsedTicks < maxMs` won't matter and the `while` loop will exit